# question on integer polynomial sequences

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, integer-sequences

Let $f:{\mathbb Z}\to {\mathbb Z}$ be a degree $d$ polynomial, and for $c\in{\mathbb Z}$ set $S_c=|\{n\in{\mathbb Z}:f(n)=c\}|$. It is easy that $S_c\le 2$ for all but finitely many $c$ (but not more, as $f$ could be a translated even polynomial), also clearly $S_c\le d$ for all $c$. Can one say something more, like, $\sum_{S_c>2}S_c=O(d)$, at least can the number of $c$ with $S_c>2$ be bounded in terms of $d$? Has there been any related research? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I first misread your question, I think I have already seen some work about that but I don't remember where, maybe in some algebraic geometry exam or arithmetic problem

Answer (score 2):

A quick search finds a cubic, $y=x^3-8281x$, with nine different $c$.

$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
'c'&'x1'&'x2'&'x3'\\
-288120&    -105&      49&      56\\
-263640 &   -104&      39 &     65\\
-150480 &    -99 &     19   &   80\\
-89760  &  -96   &  11    & 85\\
0& -91  & 0 & 91\\
89760  &  -85   & -11  &   96\\
150480  &   -80 &    -19 &     99\\
263640   &  -65 &    -39  &   104\\
288120    & -56 &    -49  &   105
\end{array}$

Comment: Solutions to $x^3-Nx=c$ occur when $N$ can be written in the form $a^2+ab+b^2$, where the $x_i$ are $a,b$ and $-a-b$.  That happens a lot when $N$ is the ptoduct of primes of the form $6k+1$

Comment: thanks a lot, that solved the issue